# QueryTables.Add application error

Tags: excel, oracle, vba

Sorry if this is quite a basic q - vb is definitely not where I spend the majority of my time...

Here's the code I'm stuck on - (Excel 2007)

```
    Set qt = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=str1, Destination:=Range("Schedule!A4"), Sql:=SQLSTRING)
    qt.Name = "TEQuery"
    qt.Refresh <-- error thrown on this line
```

When I call refresh, I get 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error, which seems too generic of an error for me to figure out what might be the issue.

In the locals window I can see that the qt and activesheet.querytables objects are behaving as I expect (non-null etc.), and I've checked my query text definitely returns a sensible result when run at the data source.  Any ideas?

ETA - I've noticed that Oracle Provider for OLE DB is missing from the data connections wizard - this is a new oracle client 11.2.0 install - got a new machine since I last used this macro...could this be the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151560/excel-2007-1004-run-time-error-refresh-query-table  Double-check your connection string uses the appropriate driver.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the connection string, as @DavidZemens says. Also, you need to change the `Range` to something like `ActiveSheet.Range("A4")`.

Comment: 100% of the time this happens to me, it's a typo in my sql statement. Even when I'm sure it's not. Make sure you're single quoting strings in your WHERE clause and your wildcards are right for the flavor of sql you're querying.

Comment: @DickKusleika I re-tried with "select * from visittable" to replace my complex query and get the same error, so I really am sure that it's not a typo...

Comment: @DavidZemens - my connection string is Connection : "OLEDB;provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=dev;User Id=uid;password=pid" : Variant/String

Comment: @DougGlancy I replaced the Range statement as suggested and it didn't make a difference

Comment: also should add in the connect string, in this context dev = tnsname of the database which is tested to be working via sqlplus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to be answering my own question for once :)

I had the 64-bit client installed, so excel 2007 obviously couldn't connect, as it's a 32-bit application and required the 32-bit client drivers.

Still - shame about the generic error message!